# LoggedIn user from C# & MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I can get Currently loggedIn user in C# like below,Can i get thisone using MVC ?
Code

```
<%=GetUserName()%>

    public string GetUserName()
{

    var user = Membership.GetUser();
    if (user == null)
    {
        return "Anonymous";
    }

    return user.UserName;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`

Great link here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302377.aspx

Comment: I found it.. can use @User.Identity.Name